# Cleaning up the attic in Plone

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

I have some old site with a Data.fs which has travelled thru aeons and accumulated cruft enough to be comparable with a yard of an average used cars dealer.

Even after removing manually folders and packing the database the Data.fs seems to take too much space.

What would be a process to hunt down and reclaim this "lost space" in Data.fs? Like printing out the object tree and relative sizes of the folders (recursively).

Answer (score 1):

See ZODB/scripts/netspace.py or [`enfold.recipe.zodbscripts`](http://dist.enfoldsystems.com/catalog/enfold.recipe.zodbscripts).  There are ways to get `netspace` installed into your buildout with all the right path info setup.  Model [after this](http://rpatterson.net/blog/migrating-a-blobstorage)  but use `netspace=ZODB.scripts.netspace:Main` instead of `migrateblobs=ZODB.scripts.migrateblobs:main`.

Comment: Does it calculate folder sizes recursively? It is unclear from the help page.

Comment: It?  There are two options in my answer.  If you've tried them and found them lacking, it might be very helpful to future googlers to document your findings by updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help track it down, but you could try:

1. Mirroring the configuration, but with a clean Data.fs;
2. Exporting (.zexp) from the live site;
3. Import into the clean;

If it all goes well, switch to the new DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at these links:

- [Update the database](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zodbupdate)
- [Inspect the database with eye](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/eye)
- [Another tip to look at the database size](http://keeshink.blogspot.com/2011/01/why-is-my-datafs-so-big.html)

The eye one looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget that no one expects the Plone Inquisition:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.inquisition